# Flatten JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, firebase

On my realtime firebase database I store my products with unique keys, i.e.,

```
- products
 |
  - KPYGghMerx_AKU8b4ki
   |
    - name: "product A"
    - price: 1.99
  - KPYNtki7UWnh5evYQgjT
   |
    - name: "product B"
    - price: 3.99
```

I retrieve this data as follows

```
this.productsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  var data = snapshot.val();
}
```

This returns the object as expected, i.e.,

```
{
  KPYGghMerx_AKU8b4ki: {
                         name: "product A"
                         price: 1.99
                       },
  KPYNtki7UWnh5evYQgjT: {
                         name: "product B"
                         price: 3.99
                       }
 }
```

What's the easiest way to map these objects into an array without the unique keys? e.g.

```
{
  name: "product A"
  price: 1.99
},
{
  name: "product B"
  price: 3.99
}
```

Comment: `Object.values({...data...})`.

Comment: `Object.keys(object).map(k=>object[k)`

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) will extract the values from an object and return it as an array:

```
Object.values({ k1: v1, k2: v2 }); //[v1, v2]
```

If you need to polyfill it you can write a simple `values` function:

```
function values(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
    return obj[key];
  });
}
```